# Contar Registros de tablas diferentes

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema que resolver.
En la lógica de negocios, un "Usuario", puede cargar lo que se conoce como "Fojas1", "Fojas2"... "Fojas5".

Estas 5 tablas de `fojasX` no se pueden normalizar en una sola porque tienen columnas diferentes. Lo único que tienen en común, es el campo usuario (que hace referencia al `id` del usuario) y la `fecha` en la que se crea el registro.

Por lo que, necesito realizar una consulta que me permita ver la cantidad de `fojas1`,...`fojas3`,...,`fojas5` cargó un usuario. El resultado seria:

```
Usuario  | # Fojas1 | # Fojas2 | # Fojas3 | # Fojas4 | # Fojas5 |

user1           5          5          3         12        32

user2           2         34         43         65        43

user3           8         40         32         23        23
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando sub-consultas, en donde en cada sub-consulta vas calculando la cantidad de registros de cada usuario, te dejo un ejemplo con las dos primeras `fojas`.

```
select   Usuario.Usuario
       , (select count(1) from Fojas1 where Fojas1.id_usuario = Usuario.id_usuario) Fojas1
       , (select count(1) from Fojas2 where Fojas2.id_usuario = Usuario.id_usuario) Fojas2
  from Usuario
```

Dado que no has publicado la estructura de tus tablas en la pregunta, he asumido los nombres de los campos, debes adaptar la consulta a la estructura real que tengas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha servido!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para que sea óptimo, primero debes agrupar y contar las fojas por usuario en cada tabla por separado indicando el origen (o categoría que le quieras dar) y luego unir los resultados, al final los sumas y le das el formato que deseas.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    usuario,
    SUM(IF(origen='fojas1',cantidad,0)) AS Fojas1,
    SUM(IF(origen='fojas2',cantidad,0)) AS Fojas2,
    SUM(IF(origen='fojas3',cantidad,0)) AS Fojas3
FROM
    (
        SELECT usuario, 'fojas1' origen, count(*) cantidad FROM fojas1 GROUP BY usuario
        UNION
        SELECT usuario, 'fojas2' origen, count(*) cantidad FROM fojas2 GROUP BY usuario
        UNION
        SELECT usuario, 'fojas3' origen, count(*) cantidad FROM fojas3 GROUP BY usuario
    ) X
GROUP BY usuario
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido.